# angular js multiple select to single drop down conversion

Tags: javascript, angular, dropdown, md-select

I have a multiselect drop down but I only want to select one of the options and then when that modal opens have that dropdown selection saved.

right now the dropdown is multi and when i close the modal, the values are still selected. I want this same functionality but in a single select dropdown. Not sure what I am missing.

```
           <md-select ng-model="itemSet.filters["names"].values" multiple aria-label="{{itemSet.filters["names"].label}}">
                 <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in itemSet.filters["names"].options">{{item.label}}</md-option>
              </md-select>
```

when I remove the multiple option in the md-select i get the error in console : this.values.forEach is not a function
this is my itemSet names object.

```
'names': {
            class: 'Filter',
            name: 'names',
            label: 'names',
            labelField: 'label',
            options: [
                            {
                                label: 'filled',
                                api: 'table',
                                key: '!VACANT'                              
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'vacant',
                                api: 'table',
                                key: 'VACANT'   
                            }
            ]
```

pretty much stuck at this point and any guidance would be super cool. I just want to be able to select one from the dropdown and then keep that there when the modal that has this opens up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in multiple mode, `ng-model` is an array of values. But since you got rid of the `multiple` attribute, it contains only the single selected value, which of course has no `forEach` method. You have not included the controller code where you iterate over `this.values`, but that's where you need to change things, as well as changing the dropdown to:

```
<md-select ng-model="itemSet.filters["names"].value" aria-label="{{itemSet.filters["names"].label}}">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in itemSet.filters["names"].options">{{item.label}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

In your controller, use `this.value` directly (assuming `this` === `itemSet.filters["names"]`).